# Registry change through python working incorrectly

Tags: python, registry, python-2.x, windows-7-x64, winreg

```
import _winreg as registry
key=registry.OpenKey(registry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings",0,registry.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
proxy=proxy_server+":"+proxy_port
registry.SetValue(key, 'ProxyEnable', registry.REG_SZ, 'dword:00000001')
registry.SetValue(key, 'ProxyServer', registry.REG_SZ, proxy)
```

I am using the above code to set proxy.But it does not add a new key in internet setting.Instead creates a new folder and put in a key named default with the values provided.

[image]

Can anybody help me on this.Really stuck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I don't understand why your code doesn't work, I *was* able to reproduce the problem as well as come up with a workaround—which is to just do the equivalent thing via the `_winreg.SetValueEx()` function.

Code with that trivial change is shown below. I also added a `r` prefix to the `key` string constant since it contains literal backslash characters (but that wasn't causing the issue). (Note I also changed the names and values of a few literals so as not to conflict with anything that might be in the registry of my own system.)

```
import _winreg as registry

proxy_server = 'some_proxy_server'  # dummy value
proxy_port = 'some_proxy_port'      # dummy value

key = registry.OpenKey(registry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                       r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings",
                       0, registry.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
proxy = proxy_server + ":" + proxy_port

# SetValue doesn't work for some reason...
#registry.SetValue(key, '_ProxyEnable', registry.REG_SZ, 'dword:00000001')
#registry.SetValue(key, '_ProxyServer', registry.REG_SZ, proxy)

# but SetValueEx does work
registry.SetValueEx(key, "_ProxyEnable", 0, registry.REG_SZ, "dword:00000001")
registry.SetValueEx(key, "_ProxyServer", 0, registry.REG_SZ, proxy)
```

I also must comment that setting `ProxyEnable` to a string value of `"dword:00000001"` instead of a `REG_DWORD` value of `1` seems a bit odd...but it's what your code was attempting to do.

[image: screenshot showing properly changed value in registry editor]

Comment: Thanx a lot.I got the same solution a while back but it was helpful of you .and when i was using set_value then it was not allowing Dword for proxy_enable but now it does allow.Thanx a lot for pointing out.

Comment: You're welcome. If you read what is written closely, in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.SetValue) they do mention that `SetValue()` will only set type `REG_SZ` string values -- so you may want to be using `SetValueEx()` anyway.

Comment: ohh Thanx a lot again.That solves most of the things except the fact that setvalue didnt work whereas setvalueex worked :)

Comment: Yes, seems like `SetValue()` should have worked. Might be a bug (in either the Python `_winreg` module or Windows-7 itself).